# Get index of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
x=pred_vec.argmax(axis=-1) 
x
o/p-array([51], dtype=int64)
```

I need to extract 51 so that it can be used to show the class to which it is labelled.

Comment: Can you provide example of what you are trying to ask here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to find the index of the maximum value using python and numpy (based on your tags ??)... If so, then try this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [3]: x = np.random.randint(1, 200, (50))                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [4]: x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[4]: 
array([186, 117, 150,  68, 118, 197, 169,  48,  90,  67, 117,  90, 133,
       141, 175, 194,  21, 107, 103,  61, 154,  87,  42,  59,  67,  66,
       198,  76, 190,   7, 188, 146, 158,  42, 106, 157,   1, 114, 185,
        58, 169,  89, 120,  81,  28,  49, 197,  73, 169, 142])

In [5]: index_max = np.argmax(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [6]: x[index_max]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: 198
```

Take a look at the [sorting, searching and counting page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.sort.html) for more options.